# How to get Google Maps Embed API key? (Google documentation is out of date)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I know this kind of question on Stack Overflow is frowned upon, but... they're also frequently answered, before the inevitable downvoting.

I'm trying to get the Google Map Embed API, but the documentation (located here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) is out of date, as the screenshot and instruction don't match what I'm actually seeing on the current Google Developers Console.

Has anyone figured this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Visit the Google Developers Console and log in with your Google
   Account
2. Create a project (button at the top).
3. Under "APIs and auth"- Credentials - create a key.
4. Under "APIs and auth"- APIs - search for Embed API and enable it.